# curl: (35) Encountered end of file

Tags: jdk

First, search the avaliable java version:

```
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz ~]# sdk list java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
 Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AdoptOpenJDK  |     | 16.0.1.j9    | adpt    |            | 16.0.1.j9-adpt      
               |     | 16.0.1.hs    | adpt    |            | 16.0.1.hs-adpt      
               |     | 11.0.11.j9   | adpt    |            | 11.0.11.j9-adpt     
               |     | 11.0.11.hs   | adpt    |            | 11.0.11.hs-adpt     
               |     | 8.0.292.j9   | adpt    |            | 8.0.292.j9-adpt     
               |     | 8.0.292.hs   | adpt    |            | 8.0.292.hs-adpt     
 Alibaba       |     | 11.0.9.4     | albba   |            | 11.0.9.4-albba      
               |     | 8.5.5        | albba   |            | 8.5.5-albba         
 Amazon        |     | 16.0.1.9.1   | amzn    |            | 16.0.1.9.1-amzn     
               |     | 11.0.11.9.1  | amzn    |            | 11.0.11.9.1-amzn    
               |     | 8.292.10.1   | amzn    |            | 8.292.10.1-amzn     
 Azul Zulu     |     | 16.0.1       | zulu    |            | 16.0.1-zulu         
               |     | 16.0.1.fx    | zulu    |            | 16.0.1.fx-zulu      
               |     | 11.0.11      | zulu    |            | 11.0.11-zulu        
               |     | 11.0.11.fx   | zulu    |            | 11.0.11.fx-zulu     
               |     | 8.0.292      | zulu    |            | 8.0.292-zulu        
               |     | 8.0.292.fx   | zulu    |            | 8.0.292.fx-zulu     
               |     | 7.0.302      | zulu    |            | 7.0.302-zulu        
               |     | 6.0.119      | zulu    |            | 6.0.119-zulu        
 BellSoft      |     | 16.0.1.fx    | librca  |            | 16.0.1.fx-librca    
               |     | 16.0.1       | librca  |            | 16.0.1-librca       
               |     | 11.0.11.fx   | librca  |            | 11.0.11.fx-librca   
               |     | 11.0.11      | librca  |            | 11.0.11-librca      
               |     | 8.0.292.fx   | librca  |            | 8.0.292.fx-librca   
               |     | 8.0.292      | librca  |            | 8.0.292-librca      
 GraalVM       |     | 21.1.0.r16   | grl     |            | 21.1.0.r16-grl      
               |     | 21.1.0.r11   | grl     |            | 21.1.0.r11-grl      
               |     | 21.1.0.r8    | grl     |            | 21.1.0.r8-grl       
               |     | 21.0.0.2.r11 | grl     |            | 21.0.0.2.r11-grl    
               |     | 21.0.0.2.r8  | grl     |            | 21.0.0.2.r8-grl     
               |     | 20.3.2.r11   | grl     |            | 20.3.2.r11-grl      
               |     | 20.3.2.r8    | grl     |            | 20.3.2.r8-grl       
               |     | 20.3.1.2.r11 | grl     |            | 20.3.1.2.r11-grl    
               |     | 20.3.1.2.r8  | grl     |            | 20.3.1.2.r8-grl     
               |     | 19.3.6.r11   | grl     |            | 19.3.6.r11-grl      
               |     | 19.3.6.r8    | grl     |            | 19.3.6.r8-grl       
               |     | 19.3.5.r11   | grl     |            | 19.3.5.r11-grl      
               |     | 19.3.5.r8    | grl     |            | 19.3.5.r8-grl       
 Java.net      |     | 18.ea.4      | open    |            | 18.ea.4-open        
               |     | 18.ea.3      | open    |            | 18.ea.3-open        
               |     | 18.ea.2      | open    |            | 18.ea.2-open        
               |     | 18.ea.1      | open    |            | 18.ea.1-open        
               |     | 17.ea.29     | open    |            | 17.ea.29-open       
               |     | 17.ea.28     | open    |            | 17.ea.28-open       
               |     | 17.ea.27     | open    |            | 17.ea.27-open       
               |     | 17.ea.26     | open    |            | 17.ea.26-open       
               |     | 17.ea.25     | open    |            | 17.ea.25-open       
               |     | 17.ea.7.lm   | open    |            | 17.ea.7.lm-open     
               |     | 17.ea.3.pma  | open    |            | 17.ea.3.pma-open    
               |     | 16.0.1       | open    |            | 16.0.1-open         
               |     | 11.0.11      | open    |            | 11.0.11-open        
               |     | 11.0.10      | open    |            | 11.0.10-open        
               |     | 11.0.2       | open    |            | 11.0.2-open         
               |     | 8.0.292      | open    |            | 8.0.292-open        
               |     | 8.0.282      | open    |            | 8.0.282-open        
               |     | 8.0.265      | open    |            | 8.0.265-open        
 Mandrel       |     | 21.1.0.0     | mandrel |            | 21.1.0.0-mandrel    
               |     | 20.3.2.0     | mandrel |            | 20.3.2.0-mandrel    
 Microsoft     |     | 16.0.1.9.1   | ms      |            | 16.0.1.9.1-ms       
               |     | 11.0.11.9.1  | ms      |            | 11.0.11.9.1-ms      
 SAP           |     | 16.0.1       | sapmchn |            | 16.0.1-sapmchn      
               |     | 11.0.11      | sapmchn |            | 11.0.11-sapmchn     
 TravaOpenJDK  |     | 11.0.9       | trava   |            | 11.0.9-trava        
               |     | 8.0.232      | trava   |            | 8.0.232-trava       
================================================================================
Use the Identifier for installation:

    $ sdk install java 11.0.3.hs-adpt
================================================================================
```

When I am using [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) to install jdk,shows this error:

```
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz ~]# sdk install java 11.0.11.hs-adpt

Downloading: java 11.0.11.hs-adpt

In progress...

######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (35) Encountered end of file
Download has failed, aborting!

Can not install java 11.0.11.hs-adpt at this time...
```

what should I do to fix it? This is my sdkman version:

```
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz ~]# sdk version

SDKMAN 5.11.6
```

Now I am enable the debbug mode, seems could not access the github.com:

```
[root@izbp19pke6x0v6ruecuy1yz etc]# sdk install java 11.0.11.hs-adpt
Validate java 11.0.11.hs-adpt for linuxx64: valid
Validation URL: https://api.sdkman.io/2/candidates/validate/java/11.0.11.hs-adpt/linuxx64
Get pre-installation hook: https://api.sdkman.io/2/hooks/pre/java/11.0.11.hs-adpt/linuxx64
Copy remote pre-installation hook: /root/.sdkman/tmp/hook_pre_java_11.0.11.hs-adpt.sh
No Linux pre-install hook found for Java 11.0.11.hs-adpt.
Completed pre-installation hook...

Downloading: java 11.0.11.hs-adpt

In progress...

######################################################################## 100.0%* About to connect() to api.sdkman.io port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 45.55.42.78...
* Connected to api.sdkman.io (45.55.42.78) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.sdkman.io
*   start date: May 30 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*   expire date: Apr 28 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*   common name: *.sdkman.io
*   issuer: CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA,O=Sectigo Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
> GET /2/broker/download/java/11.0.11.hs-adpt/linuxx64 HTTP/1.1
> Range: bytes=192792051-
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: api.sdkman.io
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.19.1
< Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 17:48:27 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< location: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.11%2B9/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.11_9.tar.gz
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.sdkman.io left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.11%2B9/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.11_9.tar.gz'
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#1)
*   Trying 13.229.188.59...
* Connected to github.com (13.229.188.59) port 443 (#1)
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=github.com,O="GitHub, Inc.",L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Mar 25 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*   expire date: Mar 30 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*   common name: github.com
*   issuer: CN=DigiCert High Assurance TLS Hybrid ECC SHA256 2020 CA1,O="DigiCert, Inc.",C=US
> GET /AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.11%2B9/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.11_9.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
> Range: bytes=192792051-
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: github.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: GitHub.com
< Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 17:48:28 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Vary: X-PJAX, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
< permissions-policy: interest-cohort=()
< Location: https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/140419044/0d0a0080-a2e2-11eb-8f2c-cb3987bd2660?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210702%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210702T174828Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=7ba2f58dd3d95397a7ff5e8f1de59e68b455c3f5da3d39ea3923be5f3bfc92db&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=140419044&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DOpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.11_9.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
< X-Frame-Options: deny
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
< Expect-CT: max-age=2592000, report-uri="https://api.github.com/_private/browser/errors"
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; block-all-mixed-content; connect-src 'self' uploads.github.com www.githubstatus.com collector.githubapp.com api.github.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-repository-file-5c1aeb.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-upload-manifest-file-7fdce7.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com cdn.optimizely.com logx.optimizely.com/v1/events translator.github.com wss://alive.github.com *.actions.githubusercontent.com wss://*.actions.githubusercontent.com online.visualstudio.com/api/v1/locations insights.github.com; font-src github.githubassets.com; form-action 'self' github.com gist.github.com; frame-ancestors 'none'; frame-src render.githubusercontent.com render-temp.githubusercontent.com viewscreen.githubusercontent.com; img-src 'self' data: github.githubassets.com identicons.github.com collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com secured-user-images.githubusercontent.com/ *.githubusercontent.com; manifest-src 'self'; media-src github.com user-images.githubusercontent.com/; script-src github.githubassets.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' github.githubassets.com; worker-src github.com/socket-worker-3f088aa2.js gist.github.com/socket-worker-3f088aa2.js
< Content-Length: 657
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: D622:5D0B:250BE1:26E4E6:60DF516B
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
{ [data not shown]
######################################################################## 100.0%* Connection #1 to host github.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/140419044/0d0a0080-a2e2-11eb-8f2c-cb3987bd2660?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210702%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210702T174828Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=7ba2f58dd3d95397a7ff5e8f1de59e68b455c3f5da3d39ea3923be5f3bfc92db&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=140419044&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DOpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.11_9.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream'
######################################################################## 100.0%* About to connect() to github-releases.githubusercontent.com port 443 (#2)
*   Trying 185.199.108.154...
* Connected to github-releases.githubusercontent.com (185.199.108.154) port 443 (#2)
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=www.github.com,O="GitHub, Inc.",L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: May 06 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*   expire date: Apr 14 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*   common name: www.github.com
*   issuer: CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> GET /140419044/0d0a0080-a2e2-11eb-8f2c-cb3987bd2660?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210702%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210702T174828Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=7ba2f58dd3d95397a7ff5e8f1de59e68b455c3f5da3d39ea3923be5f3bfc92db&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=140419044&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DOpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.11_9.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream HTTP/1.1
> Range: bytes=192792051-
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: github-releases.githubusercontent.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 416 Range Not Satisfiable
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 0
< x-amz-id-2: KwKxHMi3ygBv4f7jJzhbtztvmPi/8myDw2pEs8dqR2YOT0oqmbC1Je0h724+2d+5fmMOic1PZ6s=
< x-amz-request-id: 3FX5VJS2YEGWZ7Z9
< Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Apr 2021 19:42:24 GMT
< ETag: "0809655a9965bcd6d3eefd4b918c07c6"
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.11_9.tar.gz
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Server: AmazonS3
< Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Age: 0
< Content-Range: bytes */192792051
< Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 17:48:29 GMT
< X-Served-By: cache-dca12929-DCA, cache-nrt18321-NRT
< X-Cache: MISS, MISS
< X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-Fastly-Request-ID: 4265a81244b61078f139b612fb946a2fd90210c8
< 
* Connection #2 to host github-releases.githubusercontent.com left intact

Downloaded binary to: /root/.sdkman/tmp/java-11.0.11.hs-adpt.bin
Get post-installation hook: https://api.sdkman.io/2/hooks/post/java/11.0.11.hs-adpt/linuxx64
Copy remote post-installation hook: /root/.sdkman/tmp/hook_post_java_11.0.11.hs-adpt.sh
A Linux post-install hook was found for Java 11.0.11.hs-adpt.
Download has failed, aborting!

Can not install java 11.0.11.hs-adpt at this time...
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: the download has failed. Nothing you can do but re-download.

Comment: I have tried redownload for many times, every time shows this error@MarcusMüller

Comment: well, then the source from where you're downloading this (we have no idea what it is, what `sdk` is and so on) is simply broken, and you can't do anything about it.

Comment: sdk is sdkman the sdk management tool @MarcusMüller

Comment: Ah, thanks for adding the link there, @Dolphin!

Comment: I have add a hyperlink of sdkman official sites. @MarcusMüller

Comment: still doesn't change the fact that the downloading of the file is not within our reach, and we can't help you fix it.

Comment: @Dolphin Going by the man page, you can do `sdk list java` to get a list of valid versions. Can you do this and verify that '11.0.11.hs-adpt' is a valid version? Could be a reason for the download failing.

Comment: yes, I am sure the version is a valid version. @Haxiel

Comment: @Dolphin Right, that looks good. Can you try setting the `sdkman_debug_mode` option? It should produce some more output for the failing curl command - at the very least the URL is it trying to access.

Comment: Wait a moment, I will read the manual to found how to open the debug mode.@Haxiel

Comment: I think I must install jdk from local @Haxiel

Comment: @Dolphin Thanks for the update. The problem seems to be the 'Range: bytes=192792051-' header. The JDK download is exactly 192792051 bytes in size, so a client trying to request for more would be turned down - hence the '416 Range Not Satisfiable' error. Can you try removing the `/root/.sdkman/tmp/java-11.0.11.hs-adpt.bin` file, and then triggering the install? It might resolve the issue. And as you said, you can always download the JDK file manually and install it. The URL is right there in the debug output.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.  I just spooled up a new Linux server, and I've tried installing Java from multiple vendors using SDKMAN, and each time it fails with the error message, "Download has failed, aborting!"  So, it has nothing to do with the server it's being downloaded from, since each vendor has their own URL.  I really love sdkman, I just wish it actually worked.